# increase query performance in SqlCipher database

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher-android

I encrypted my SQliteDatabase with `sqlcipher` in android.
when I select 11000 record, it takes 9 seconds while this query in normal sqlite database takes just 3 seconds.
How can I solve this?